# Ratio Estimator as WLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, estimators, weighted-regression, ratio

Apologies in advance for whatever rules this post breaks.

I'm looking at a problem where we're currently using a ratio estimator for a certain survey. $$r = \dfrac{\sum_i{y_i}}{\sum_i{x_i}}$$

This is supposed to be equivalent to a WLS model with no intercept weighted to the reciprocal of x, which is good because I want to add in more explanatory variables while maintaining continuity with the current process. I can follow along with the derivation for why they're the same.

```
n <- 100
x <- runif(n,0,10)
m <- 0.5
e <- rnorm(n,0,2)
y <- m*x+e
(r = sum(y)/sum(x))
[1] 0.4914346
coef(lm(y ~ 0 + x, weights = 1/x))
0.4914346
```

So far, so good. The problem is when there are data points with $x=0$. Obviously lm throws an error if you pass inf in as a weight, but I figure that the weight should be irrelevant at 0 in any case. If we're trying to minimise $$ \sum_{i=1}^n w_i(y_i-bx_i)^2$$ then at $x_i=0$ changing $b$ won't alter the weighted sum of squares so it matters not what the weight is there.

Or to put it another way, if we're forcing the line through the origin then points where $x=0$ have no leverage.

```
n <- 100
#x <- runif(n,0,10)
x <- sample(0:10,n,replace=T)
m <- 0.5
e <- rnorm(n,0,2)
y <- m*x+e
(r = sum(y)/sum(x))
[1] 0.4341093
coef(lm(y ~ 0 + x, weights = ifelse(x==0,0,1/x)))
0.4320292    # not the same.
```

Is there some weight I can put in here that will give me the same value? Changing the value at zero seems to have no effect.

```
coef(lm(y ~ 0 + x, weights = ifelse(x==0,100,1/x)))
0.4320292
```

I think the references I've seen have just asserted the two approaches are equivalent, but adding in points at $x=0$ changes the ratio estimator without altering the WLS estimate. Is it only true for $x>0$? Is one approach to be preferred? Does anyone know of any references that mention this?

Answer (score 0):

Your "ratio estimator" differs from the WLS estimator because the numerator stays the same no matter whether there are zeros in $x$ or not. Modifying it to `sum(y[x!=0])/sum(x)` will give the weighted version you obtained from `lm`.

You are right that the ratio estimator then strictly speaking is not the WLS estimator with the given weighting scheme anymore, because the weighting scheme amounts to removing *tuples of observations* $(y_i,x_i)$ for which $x_i=0$.

Comment: Yeah, I'd figured that, but I was hoping to adjust the WLS algorithm to reproduce the ratio estimator rather than the other way around. My suspicion is this isn't possible. I think I might just abandon continuity with the current approach, the ratio estimator feels like some relic out of the pre-digital age. Also it's often applied in situations like mine, where both x and y are strictly non-negative. This means the error term near the origin is necessarily misspecified. And then we end up weighting those observations the highest... I don't like that at all.

Comment: Indeed, I do not see an obvious way to do so, as the ratio estimator treats the numerator and denominator separately, basically, while WLS applies weights to both.

Comment: I just found that if you have no points on the x axis you can regress x on y instead, and then take the reciprocal. Obviously normally you can't switch which variable is independent, but with this weighting scheme and no intercept you can (as you can see just by looking at the equivalent ratio estimator). This happens to solve the problem in my case as we were already excluding all points on the x axis.